# Python One Way Encryption

Tags: python, encryption, passwords

I want to check a user `input()` against a password, but I do not want to store the actual password anywhere. I am thinking to encrypt the input and the password in the same way, then check those against each other. However, I am unable to find anything on one-way encryption in Python.

1). Is this the best solution? (If not, what is the best solution?)

2). How would I implement this?

I tried to use the built-in `hash()` function, but every time I run the program, the same value generates a different hash.

Comment: What you are looking for (one way encryption) is called hashing. Python's `hash()` function is not a cryptographic hash, it's merely for quickly finding elements in a set or a similar data structure. Passwords are usually hashed using `sha1` or better algorithms. You should also research the concept of a "salt" to alleviate attacks that use "rainbow tables". That's a lot of reading.

Comment: Search for Scrypt, Bcrypt or Argon2 as they provide the requested functionality.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Thank you! I was able to get it to work using Scrypt.